# Bash Combine Replacement and Sub String Extraction in One Step

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, string

For a string in this format:

```
./my-site.sub.domain.com
```

I would like to remove the `.`,`-`, and `/`, and trim the remainder to 16 characters: `mysitesubdomainc`

I've done this

```
mysite="./my-site.sub.domain.com"
mysite=${mysite//[\.|\/|-]//}
mysite=${mysite:0:16}
echo $mysite
mysitesubdomainc
```

Is there a way to combine the replacement and sub-string extraction?

Comment: There's a bug in your code - the first replacement will replace pipe characters as well. There's no separator inside a [character set](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html).

Comment: Thank you. `mysite=${mysite//[\.\/-]/}` is all I need.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to chain the Bash built-in [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073), but of course this can be done in a single line with external tools like `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/[\.\/-]//g;s/^\(.\{16\}\).*/\1/' <<< "./my-site.sub.domain.com"
mysitesubdomainc
```

Unfortunately this very quickly turns into unmaintainable code, and is probably less efficient than using Bash internals, so I would advise against it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use zsh?

```
$ echo ${${mysite//[\.\/-]/}:0:16}
mysitesubdomainc
```

(I slightly modified you code)

Answer (score 1):

As @l0b0 said, I don't think this can be done in a single step in the shell but it's simple enough to do with external tools (this assumes the string is saved in the variable `$s`):

```
$ perl -pe 's#[.\-/]##g' <<<$s | grep -oP .{16}
mysitesubdomainc
```